# Deploying multiple web Apps on Azure App Service.. Is there any implications of this

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-storage-account

I have a client coming on board to Azure from other cloud service provider. They would like to host up to 10 web apps on Azure and cost is really an issue for them.
Normally I'm suppose to create VM's that would host each of these web Apps; but they can't afford the price. Hence the choice of deploying all of them on the same Azure App service plan.
I think Azure App service offers only 50gb storage. The 10 Web Apps would require storage capacity far more than 50gb; is it scalable or can we link each of these Apps to an Azure storage account. And also is there any implications for deploying multiple web Apps on an Azure App Service plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An App Service Plan is designed to handle multiple web apps/Function apps, use BLOB Storage or similar for your data it will scale to whatever you need, depending on your needs you can add further services like Azure Front Door to load balance multiple apps on multiple app service plans

One important thing to remember is that the app service plan has limitations with outbound connections so even if each of your webapps are not so busy the sum of them all might bring you over the limit so be very careful how you handle your outbound connections.

Comment: Thanks.. But will the BLOB storage be linked to each of the web Apps or a single storage account be linked to the  Azure App service plan on which the Apps are deployed.
Storage accounts are a bit expensive will this approach not be costlier than the VM approach thereby defeating the aim of reducing cost

Comment: @VennyYoung you can choose to share the BLOB account or not, its really up to you and what your traffic pattern looks like

Answer (score 1):

An App Service Plan is capable to run multiple Web Apps, each in its own sandbox. It's like a VM but as a PaaS service.  Note that the storage included in the plan will be shared across all Web Apps so you'll have to use Azure Storage if you want to store more data.